# force browser to render pages in IE 10 Compatability View Mode

Tags: html, asp-classic, cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I have a home page which has links to other applications. A few are in asp and a few in asp.net . I want to force the browser to render the page in IE 10 Compatibility view mode such that all the other pages are also rendered in the same manner . And this should not be done manually using developer tools.

Comment: Did you tried using meta? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Comment: Did you tried my answer ? Did it solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a HTTP header to tell IE to use the latest compatibility mode available for it (If using IE 8, will be IE 8 Compatibility mode, if IE10, will use IE 10 Compatibility mode) :

```
Response.AddHeader "X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"
```